# iReport multiplying in percentage pattern

Tags: formatting, jasper-reports

I'm working with iReport 2.0.5 (because I have to) and I have a little issue formatting percentages. 
When I use an unformatted double this is what I get:

```
0
22,22
5,555 (this is the average of the whole group)
100
100  (this is the average of the whole group)
```

The average is calculated OK

But when I set the pattern **#,##0.00 %** using iReport 2.0.5 this happens:

```
0,00 %
2.222,00 %
555,50 % (this is the average of the whole group)
10.000,00 %
10.000,00 % (this is the average of the whole group)
```

How do I stop the values from changing?

Comment: add sample jrxml code

Comment: `<textField isStretchWithOverflow="true" pattern="#,##0.00 %" isBlankWhenNull="false" evaluationTime="Now" hyperlinkType="None"  hyperlinkTarget="Self" >
     <reportElement
      x="694"
      y="0"
      width="88"
      height="20"
      key="textField-8"/>
     <box></box>
     <textElement textAlignment="Right" verticalAlignment="Middle">
      <font/>
     </textElement>
    <textFieldExpression   class="java.lang.Double"><![CDATA[$F{percentageVar}]]></textFieldExpression>
    </textField>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`22,22` is `2.222,00 %` what you need is `0.2222`  so this is a solution (just dived by 100)

In old version expression it is achieved like this:

```
new Double($F{percentageVar}.doubleValue()/100d)
```

So your `textField` (hoping that `$F{percentageVar}` is  never `null`) is

```
<textField isStretchWithOverflow="true" pattern="#,##0.00 %" isBlankWhenNull="false" evaluationTime="Now" hyperlinkType="None" hyperlinkTarget="Self" > <reportElement x="694" y="0" width="88" height="20" key="textField-8"/> <box></box> <textElement textAlignment="Right" verticalAlignment="Middle"> <font/> </textElement> <textFieldExpression class="java.lang.Double"><![CDATA[new Double($F{percentageVar}.doubleValue()/100d)]]></textFieldExpression> </textField>
```

Comment: Thank you very much. This is working properly now.
Jasper is, after all, Java. I was always thinking about the problem wrong.

Answer (score 6):

What you can also do, without changing (dividing) your value:

Try this pattern:

```
 #,##0.00 ' %'
```

when you put **%** in quotes ( '%' ), then your value will not be multiplied with 100.

Cheers!